# Not equal to operator for MongoDB query in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have one query in MongoDB like below,

```
db.getCollection('Student')
.find({_id: 123, $where:"this.section != this.upperSection"})
```

How to convert this query to execute from C# code?

I tried using the below code but that didn't work. Can you guide me?

```cs
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;

var filter = builder.Not("section ", "upperSection");
```

Sample Mongo docs - & the expected outcome should be doc2

```
//doc1
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "section" : "X",
    "upperSection" : "X"
}

//doc2
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "section" : "X",
    "upperSection" : "Y"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the query as `BsonDocument`.

```cs
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter = new BsonDocument("$expr", 
    new BsonDocument("$ne",
        new BsonArray { "$section", "$upperSection" }
    )
);
```

> Output

[image]